# Running JVM 1.4.2 on a modern PC/Mac

Tags: windows-7, mac-osx, bladecenter, java

I need to access an old IBM blade center's KVM. It uses Java and asks for 1.4.02_08 and above.

I tried with a Mac (JM 7) and two PCs (win7, JM6) to no avail. I installed the old java but it won't run the old version on a PC.

What OS/Browser/JVM combination should I use? How do I run multiple Java versions side by side?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use IE5/6/7/8 on Windows XP or older, because that's how it was back in the day of JVM 1.4.  You can run multiple versions of Java at the same time.  The problem is forcing the browser to use the version you want.  You might get lucky with IE10 and Windows 7 in Windows XP Compatibilty Mode, but it'll be hit or miss.

As of IE8, I believe you can select which version of Java you want to use.  I can't confirm for anything older than that.

In IE:

1. Go to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced
2. Scroll down to Java
3. Check the version of Java you want to use
4. Restart IE

Try to load the utility again.  Note: you may need to run the site in compatibility view mode.  And, you might have to reset the browser to its default settings, because it may have cached previous options, like; "don't run this java app" or "don't trust this app".

It would also help to add the utility/server address to your Local Intranet Sites list in Tools > Internet Options > Security